# enable DNS pre-resolution and TCP pre-connection

Tags: google-chrome

How can I enable DNS pre-resolution and TCP pre-connection in a Chrome browser (Mac OS X), when the `chrome://dns` page tells that "DNS pre-resolution and TCP pre-connection is disabled"?

[image]

Comment: Apparently `uBlock` addon  blocks this from working and can be toggled `off` in the addon.

Comment: `chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/dashboard.html` <- URL to edit uBlock's settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the advanced settings and called "Predict network actions to improve page load performance"

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I had the behavior as in Q&A above in Chrome on Windows:

- `chrome://dns` says "DNS pre-resolution and TCP pre-connection is disabled.",

whereas

- `chrome://settings` shows "Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly" as ticked

**I was wondering how this relates to  `<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//some.domain">` and `<link rel="preconnect" href="https://some.domain">`.**

## Browsers:

- Chrome 67 stable with uBlock
- Chrome 68 beta (no extensions)

## Before the tests

- have `chrome://dns` tell you that the services are disabled (perhaps by installing uBlock)
- serve the following HTMLs on localhost

  ```
  <!doctype html><html><head>
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ajax.googleapis.com">
  </head><body></html>

  <!doctype html><html><head>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com">
  </head><body></html>
  ```

## Test 1: with Fiddler

- go to `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and clear host cache
- enable Fiddler and make it listen to the traffic
- open new tab in Chrome on `http://localhost`
- observe Fiddler to have a *"Tunnel to ajax.googleapis.com:443"* session

## Test 2: without Fiddler

- go to `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and clear host cache
- open new tab in Chrome on `http://localhost`
- refresh `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and observe DNS entries

## Results and conclusions:

- Chrome 67 stable with uBlock: `preload` always works; `dns-prefetch` is blocked by uBlock if uBlock setting `Disable pre-fetching (to prevent any connection for blocked network requests)` is enabled
- Chrome 68 beta (no extensions): both `dns-prefetch` and `preload` work
- At this point it's hard to say which of those behaviors are features or bugs and in which part of the stack.