# How do you test the effects of dns-prefetch and preconnect

Tags: http, dns, prefetch

I'm trying out the `<link rel="dns-prefetch">` and `<link rel="preconnect">` tags and I'm trying to see whether they help for my site. I can't find any online resources about how verify if these hints are working using browser dev tools, extensions, or other software. It seems like you just evaluate whether they may be useful to you based on some criteria and then drop them in and hope for the best.

In my case, I have a single page app that renders the entire contents of the `<body>` in the browser, so the browser can't really scan the initial HTML to lookahead for domains to resolve so it seemed like this might be useful for me.

Comment: You need to find a way to test the server a great many times (1000) and statistically calculate the waterfall data with the optimization and without. this so be repeat for each browser type (FF, chrome, IE, safari...). I do not know of such a tool..

Comment: Slightly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034706/

Answer (score 10):

In order to just make sure that the features are working in a given browser (very synthetic test), you can do as follows

## Test 1: test `dns-prefetch` (just DNS) with Chrome

- serve the following HTML on localhost

  ```
  <!doctype html><html><head>
      <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ajax.googleapis.com">
  </head><body></html>
  ```
- go to `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and clear host cache
- open new tab in Chrome on `http://localhost`
- refresh `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and observe it to have the DNS entry - this confirms that DNS resolution has been done

## Test 2: test `preconnect` (DNS+TLS+TCP) with Chrome and Fiddler (Windows-only)

- serve the following HTML on localhost

  ```
  <!doctype html><html><head>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com">
  </head><body></html>
  ```
- go to `chrome://net-internals/#dns` and clear host cache
- start Fiddler and make it listen to the traffic
- open new tab in Chrome on `http://localhost`
- observe Fiddler to have a *"Tunnel to ajax.googleapis.com:443"* session - this confirms that DNS resolution and TLS handshake were done (and you can probably trust the browser that it established a TCP connection too)

Comment: The example HTML for test 1 is also  rel="preconnect", should be "dns-prefetch" :)

Comment: Not seeing any DNS entries in chrome://net-internals/#dns
Though Host resolver cache option is there

Answer (score 9):

Run your page through webpagetest.org. Requests to the domains you specified in your dns-prefetch or preconnect tags should begin sooner because the initial connection will have been established.

This will show in the waterfall graph, for those requests - at the left of the bar the DNS, connect and SSL (if applicable) segments will detach from the response and move to the left in the waterfall, to reflect the fact that they occurred earlier.

Comment: Is there a way to test it locally? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To test the impact on DNS time in a very granular and customizable way, here's another approach: HAR file parsing.

Load the site with the network panel open, then [download the HAR file](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting)

Read that HAR file in as JSON (either in Node with readFile, or browser with FileReader), and you'll end up with an object like this:

```js
const har = {
  log: {
    version: {},
    creator: {},
    page: {},
    entries: {}, // <-- You want these
  }
}
```

Then you can look at (and do math with) `har.log.entries[idx].timing.dns`, so you can answer things like:

How much total time was spent waiting for DNS fetching?

```js
const ms = har.log.entries.map(e => e.timing.dns).reduce(sum); // NOTE: should rm all the -1s
console.log('Total DNS Time: ' + ms);

// Total DNS Time: 242 ms
```

Which requests were waiting for DNS at all?

```js
const display = har.log.entries
  .filter(e => dnsTime(e) > 0)
  .map(e => ({
      method: e.request.method,
      url: e.request.url,
      dns: dnsTime(e),
    })
  );

console.table(display);
// Prints a nice table with things like: [GET foo.com 72ms]
```