# html\http dns-prefetch and preconnect proof

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

i wanted to test whether my browser honors [resource hints](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/), namely dns-prefetch, preconnect, etc.

i created a simple html file, name `index.html` as follows

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//www.wikipedia.org">
</head>
<body>
</html>
```

and i started nginx locally to serve `index.html` as follow

```sh
docker run --rm -it -p 80:80 -v $PWD:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx:latest
```

i launched [chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) (Version 88.0.4283.0 (Developer Build) (x86_64)), and moved to [browse as guest user](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6130773) (to guarantee a new browser session).

i started [netlog dump](https://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/providing-network-details) (started the netlog dump), in a new tab i navigated to `localhost` and `index.html` was served, and then i stopped the dump.

i opened the netlog dump in [netlog-viewer](https://netlog-viewer.appspot.com/#import) and navigated to the DNS tab, but there was no record for `www.wikipedia.org`.

1. what is missing in order to see that the `dns-prefetch` resource hint worked as expected?
2. same question as the previous with respect to `preconnect`

i looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50929119), but it didn't help me. also tried to append `crossorigin` to the `<link>` tag, but still didn't change anything.

**UPDATE:**

to further debug the issue, i added `<link rel="preconnect" href="//localhost:8080">`, started another local http server on a different port, which logs when connection is established, and repeat the steps mentioned before. yet, there was no logs indicating on the `preconnect`.